# Parse url like wordpress /year/month/post_id

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, parsing, url

I am building my own frontend interface to my wordpress site.
What I cannot solve is how to show friendly url like wordpress does.

I want go from this:

> designals.net/demo/index.php?id=BACARDI

to this:

> designals.net/demo/2014/04/BACARDI

Should I use .htaccess?

Thanks you very much in advance!!

**EDIT**: I am building my frontend from scratch (querying from database using my own php code), so wordpress settings may not take effects on my site, I need to match url rules of boths sides.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Permalinks, and change it to the "Day and Name" option.

Comment: But remember I am building my own frontend view from scratch (using html, php, css, etc), so I need to match url rules of wordpress and my build.

Comment: @GuillermoDelicia You should be building a custom WordPress theme.

Comment: OK thanks but I am not interested really, I want to avoid all the WordPress functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use .htaccess. Go to Settings->permalinks and change the settings there